# How to solve 'MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 18.215.96.27017 closed'?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

When I try to connect my Node Express to a MongoDB server, I face this error:

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The error looks like your replicaset lost the primary node. Since you are using atlas this will be recovered soon as it is fully managed.